# Youtube api Get copyright Videos by channel

Tags: php, api, video, youtube-api

Is it possible to get all videos that have copyright on them from a youtube username
So i need all videos that are on this page:

https://www.youtube.com/my_videos_copyright

With or without api authentication doesn't matter

Thanks